# Oracle SQL Foreign Key constraint that ignores null or historic values

Tags: sql, oracle, null, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to add a constrain to a database table that I want to modify. I want to add a constraint on a column so it references a primary key of another tables. Easy enough, I just have to add a foreign key constraint. The problem is that the column already has some values that are null or something that is not part of the table I will be referencing.

My question is how do I add a constraint that references a primary key but can also accept null values (the primary key always has a value) and how to ignore the existing values so far. Is it possible? If the second part is not, I am thinking I could always write a script that updates all the nonsense values (they have a format of sort if that I can reg ex) to null so they only thing I have to figure out is how to add a foreign key constraind that also accepts null values

Comment: The second part is not possible.  You cannot add a constraint that doesn't actually constrain the field.  `Null` values are fine to have in Foreign Keys (Not sure about Oracle, but that's how it is in SQL Server).  But if you wanted an actual constraint, you would need to update those existing values to be relevant.

Comment: If the column for which you're trying to create a foreign key constraint is not a primary key at the same time then just add a constraint. Foreign keys, as @Siyual said, can contain NULL values. In this case some rows won't reference to a primary key of another table.

Comment: @Siyual, that's not true for Oracle. You can add constraints with the `NOVALIDATE` option which means they are only validated for new/updated rows.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Really?  Oh wow, that's interesting - I did not know that.  Learn something new everyday, I suppose, hah.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, there's nothing stopping you from adding a referential constraint on a column that has NULLs - foreign key constraints are only enforced for non-NULL values.

Secondly, if there are existing values that do not exist in the parent table, and you can't fix them, you do have the option in Oracle to make the constraint only validated for newly inserted or updated rows, using the `NOVALIDATE` option, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES parent (id) NOVALIDATE;
```

The only downside to using the `NOVALIDATE` option is that the query optimizer will not rely on the FK constraint, and will execute queries with the assumption that there may be rows that do not have a matching parent row.

It would be a good idea if you are able to fix the missing values, afterwards to alter the constraint to `VALIDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys can not contain NULL values in all databases ([proof](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp))

To add a foreign key you should do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_table1_2
FOREIGN KEY (column1)
REFERENCES table2(column2);
```